# Replicating a file system

Tags: java, file-system, swing, gui

The goal of this is just to practice. I went off on a self-challenge to replicate something(So the names of the parts can be ignored), I'm not done yet (Though what is here is fully runnable), but have enough code that I thought it could merit taking a moment to examine whether I could be doing anything a cleaner way.

This is the main class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Font;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class EditorMain {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

    EditorMain() {
        setUIFont (
            new javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource("Verdana", Font.ITALIC, 11));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        final int WIDTH = 1000;
        final int HEIGHT = 600;

        JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel();
        imagePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));
        imagePanel.add(new JButton(new ImageIcon("Assets/folder.png")));
        imagePanel.add(new JButton(new ImageIcon("Assets/save.png")));
        imagePanel.add(new JButton(new ImageIcon("Assets/printer.png")));


        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Need Help?");
        JMenuItem openMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
        JMenuItem cutMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Cut");
        JMenuItem copyMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Copy");
        JMenuItem pasteMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Paste");                                                                  

        openMenuItem.addActionListener(
            e -> {
                if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) 
                    == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                }
            }
        );

        fileMenu.add(openMenuItem);
        editMenu.add(cutMenuItem);
        editMenu.add(copyMenuItem);
        editMenu.add(pasteMenuItem);

        // add menus to menubar
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);

        // put the menubar on the frame
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Trace Functional Method Specification Input Tool");
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);


        final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        JTable table = new JTable(new ColorTableModel());

        table.setRowHeight(40);
        JScrollPane jscroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        jscroll.setBounds(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true); 
        panel.add(jscroll);
        panel.add(imagePanel);
        panel.setToolTipText("Example of helpful message!");

        ((JComponent) jscroll.getParent()).revalidate();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Input/Output Definition", panel);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Data Type Definition", new JPanel());
        tabbedPane.addTab("Access Methods and Event Descriptors Definition",
                new JPanel());
        tabbedPane.addTab("Auxiliary Functions Definition", new JPanel());
        tabbedPane.addTab("Output Behaviour Specification", new JPanel());

        JPanel header = new JPanel();
        header.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Module Interface Specification");
        title.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 20));
        header.add(title);
        header.add(imagePanel);

        tabbedPane.setBounds(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.add(header, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); 
        frame.add(tabbedPane);
        frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("Assets/Icon.png").getImage());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : 
                UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(EditorMain::new);
    }

    public static void setUIFont(javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource f) {
        java.util.Enumeration keys = UIManager.getDefaults().keys();
        while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            Object key = keys.nextElement();
            Object value = UIManager.get(key);
            if (value != null
                    && value instanceof javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource)
                UIManager.put(key, f);
        }
    }
}
```

The ColorTableModel class:

```
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

class ColorTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    Object rowData[][] = {
        { "", "", Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE },
        { "","", Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.TRUE }
    };

    String columnNames[] = { "Variable Name", "Data Type" , "Input", "Output"};

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return rowData.length;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        return rowData[row][column];
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        return (getValueAt(0, column).getClass());
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
        rowData[row][column] = value;
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'd like a general review, with an emphasis on tidying my code/increasing readability.

Comment: A somewhat related github repository which is intended to help implementing filesystems that follow the nio.file api: https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-base

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### `EditorMain`

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
// ...You get the idea.
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
```

At this point, you may as well just do the one `*` import statement:

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

Note that the `TableModel` import is *not* on the list of things I said to replace. It's unused, so you should get rid of it. Ditto for `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

```
EditorMain() {
```

This should *probably* be `public`; you very rarely need to use package-private, and this doesn't seem like one of those cases. Especially since the class is `public` and contains `main(String[] args)`.

You never seem to add click listeners to `cut`, `copy`, and `pasteMenuItem`. I suppose this is because you're in a basic version of the code, but at the very least, add a placeholder comment like

```
//TODO: Add listeners to these
```

between `openMenuItem` and the other three. It'll keep you from forgetting.

```
JScrollPane jscroll = new JScrollPane(table);
```

`jscroll` is a terrible name. Admittedly, there's really not a *good* name for a `JScrollPane` wrapper, but what I'd do is something like `tableScroller`, so it's at least clear what it's wrapped around.

```
} catch (Exception e) {
```

This is very often *terrible* idea. Always catch the most specific exceptions you can, with as many catch blocks as is reasonable -- in this case, you'll want to refer to [the `UIManager#setLookAndFeel` Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#setLookAndFeel-java.lang.String-). They tend to list the exceptions (at least in my experience) in the same order that you should have list them when writing your try/catch blocks.

```
javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource
```

You use the fully qualified name at least twice. Why not `import` it at the top?

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(EditorMain::new);
```

Nothing to criticize here. Just wanted to give you an internet pat-on-the-back for doing this. It's a very good idea to separate graphics and processing.

```
for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
        break;
    }
}
```

This took me a couple of seconds to get and a read through the docs -- it might be worth it to add a comment along the lines of

```
// Use the theme called "Nimbus" if it's installed.
```

`java.util.Enumeration` is a raw type; it takes a generic, so you should use it with one. In this case, it'd just be `java.util.Enumeration<Object>`, but it'll help prevent errors later on if you add the generic now.

In `openMenuItem.addActionListener`, you never actually used `file`. I'm assuming that's for later, but I wanted to point it out anyway; I'd add a `System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());` so you can see that it's the right file.

#### `ColorTableModel`

I'd recommend adding a check wherever you access an array with a value from a parameter. While it's not *strictly* necessary, since trying to call anything out-of-bounds will properly throw an error, getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` when it doesn't look like you're accessing an array can be confusing. It's as simple as wrapping it in a try/catch and throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` if you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` -- i.e. something like this:

```
// Same idea for all of them, so I'm just using `get` as an example.
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    try {
        rowData[row][column];
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "(%s, %s) is an invalid location!", row, column), e);
    }
}
```

I used [`String#format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) because I personally find it nicer to use. Concatenation would work equally well.

```
public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
    return (getValueAt(0, column).getClass());
}
```

This should return a `Class<?>` to conform with `AbstractTableModel`.